# Get today's Jenkins builds and and check if there are any success builds using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to get if there are any success builds in today's date.

I am able to check all builds and get success builds info using the code below, but I am unable to filter and loop within today's builds only, instead of looping through all builds.

```
$successInfo = $false
    foreach ($build in $buildsInfo) {
        $buildDate = Get-Date($build.timestamp) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        if ($build.result -eq "SUCCESS" -and $buildDate -eq $currentDate) {
            $successInfo = $true
            break
        }
    }
```

To check today's build I tried different approaches; below is one of them:

```
$startOfDay = (Get-Date).Date.ToShortDateString()
$todaysBuilds = $commitStageInfo.builds | Where-Object { (Get-Date($_.timestamp) -match $startOfDay) }
```

Note: My Jenkins build's timestamp is in `timestamp=1711064553748` format.

Comment: No it is not related to any specific version of powershell

Comment: As an aside: It's best to pseudo method syntax: Instead of `Get-Date($build.timestamp) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`, use `Get-Date $build.timestamp -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments.